# ejecutar un js cada vez que se recorra un foreach laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, foreach

Estoy realizado una función para indicar que un formulario ya fue revisado.

Para esto tengo un botón el cual me lleva al formulario, y dentro del formulario hay otro botón de aprobar que me cambia un valor en la base de datos de `0` a `1`.

El js consulta un campo y si hay `1` el botón cambia a verde indicando que ya fue revisado. Funciona perfecto con un botón, pero como la lista la tengo en un `foreach` de laravel, solo me funciona para el primer botón.
Utilizo `window.onload`, pero no sé como llamar la funcion cada vez que se recorra.

**resultado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**blade**

```
@foreach ($listform as $list)    
<tr>
    <td>{{$list->fecha_empaque}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->lote}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->linea->nombre_maquina}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->producto->nombre_producto}}</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>{{$list->ingeniero}}</td>

        <td> <input id="estado" type="number" value="{{$list->revision}}"></td>

    <td>
        <a id="resultado" href="{{route('revisar',$list->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-raised btn-lg" >
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-check-all"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**js**

```
window.onload= function cambiar (){

    var estado =document.getElementById("estado").value;
    
    if(estado == 1){
    
        document.getElementById("resultado").style.backgroundColor ="green";
    
    }
    
}
```

**botón**

```
<a id="resultado" href="{{route('revisar',$list->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-raised btn-lg" >
   <i class="zmdi zmdi-check-all"></i> 
</a>
```

Esto cambia bien pero solo funciona el primer botón

Comment: ¿Donde está el foreach de laravel? Ten en cuenta que en html la [propiedad `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id) de una etiqueta debe ser única en todo el documento

Comment: mmm pero entonses como podria hacer para poder asignarle la funcion a todos estos botones ??? 
gracias por tu comentario

Comment: Por lo que veo, lo del color del botón lo puedes hacer directamente con laravel al crear la tabla, pues depende del valor de `$list->revision`. Algo así `class="btn {{ $list->revision? 'btn-success': 'btn-warning' }} btn-raised btn-lg"`.

Comment: si me funciono tenias la razon no se me habia pasado por la cabeza utilizar css para esto  gracias si poner tu comentario como respuesta con gusto la apruebo gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa de que "solo funciona para el primer botón", es que al tener el `<input id="estado" type="number" value="{{$list->revision}}">` dentro de un `foreach`, se le está asignando el mismo `id` a todos, y en html la [propiedad `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id) de una etiqueta debe ser única en todo el documento.

Pero antes de intentar arreglar eso con el mismo enfoque que estás planteando, ten en cuenta que para el color inicial del botón, no necesitas js, pues al momento de crear la tabla, ya tienes el valor inicial `$list->revision` que determina que color debe llevar.

Entonces, te propongo otra solución, que es hacerlo directamente con laravel al crear la tabla.

Algo así, siguiendo lo que estabas intentando hacer con js:

```
<a href="{{route('revisar',$list->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-raised btn-lg" @if($list->revision) style="backgroundColor: green;" @endif>
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-check-all"></i>
</a>
```

O usando las clases de bootstrap:

```
<a href="{{route('revisar',$list->id)}}" class="btn {{ $list->revision? 'btn-success': 'btn-warning' }} btn-raised btn-lg">
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-check-all"></i>
</a>
```